# Parsing and validating conditional IF in PEG parser

Tags: javascript, bnf, peg, pegjs

Trying to parse a single line conditional where code tries to test the left hand is equal to the right hand.

```js
{
  user = {id: 'abc123'}
  function_name() {...}
}

if (user.id === 'abc123...') { function_name() }
```

I've so far looked at these posts [PEG-php parsing if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800010/peg-php-parsing-if-statement) and [How to describe conditional statement (if-then-else) using PEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749318/how-to-describe-conditional-statement-if-then-else-using-peg)

PEG syntax is very alien to me, and I'm sure if it's even the right methodology for my needs. Might be overkill.

Currently using peg.js/peggy.js

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, I will try to give you a starting point,

this is a grammar that would consume your example intput.

```js
Code = (Condition / Curly / Statement)+

Curly = '{' code: Code+ '}' { return {nested: code}}

Statement = $([^{}]+)

Condition = _ 'if' _ '(' lhs:term '===' rhs:term ')' _ body: Code {
  return {condition: {lhs, rhs}, body}
}
term = $[^{}()=]+
_ "whitespace"
  = [ \t\n\r]*
```

For the condition part it will produce

```
  {
      "condition": {
         "lhs": "user.id ",
         "rhs": " 'abc123...'"
      },
      "body": [
         {
            "nested": [
               [
                  " function_name() "
               ]
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
```

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness. What you've given above has given me a good starting point. Basically I wanted to do is actively check if x === y, then run the function. The use case is a roundabout way to write some javascript inside json. If the expression is valid, some global function can be called.

Comment: The [JavaScript example](https://github.com/peggyjs/peggy/blob/main/examples/javascript.pegjs) will give you some more ideas to work with.